# prepositions - "increase of" vs "increase in"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation

Which one is correct or if both are correct, is there any difference?

> The change is a 10 percent increase of tuition
>
> The change is a 10 percent increase in tuition

Answer (score 7):

*There has been an increase **of** ten per cent **in** the tuition fees.*

*The minister announced that there would be an increase **of** fifty cents **in** the tax on fuel.*

There is generally a rise **in** the amount or number of something. An increase **of** X tells us the amount or percentage of the rise.

Comment: So you mean in them example I provided, the second form is correct in the first form is incorrect?

Comment: @tunny Is "in" also the only correct choice if I talk about abstract quantities, as in "we observe a strong decrease of y as a function of x"?

Comment: @Aliweb that's right. "increase in tuition" is the right one.